# how to import custom animation xml in wallpaper app?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper

i have a source which is a sample wallpaper app, i want to import a animation xml

```
    public WallpaperEngine(Resources r) {
        image01=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r,R.drawable.fire01);
        image02=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r,R.drawable.fire02);
        bg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r,R.drawable.hktv);
        px=1;
        translateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.translate_animation);
    }
```

but there is a error at line translate_animation

```
cannot find symbol variable translate_animation
```

How can i solve this?

------update------

```
package com.example.android.livewallpaper;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FireLiveWallpaper extends WallpaperService {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine() {
        return new WallpaperEngine(getResources());
    }

    public class WallpaperEngine extends Engine {
        private final Handler handler=new Handler();        
        private Bitmap image; //Image
        private Bitmap image01; //Image01 for fire01.PNG
        private Bitmap image02; //Image02 for fire02.PNG
        private Bitmap bg;
        private Paint paint = new Paint();
        private int    px=0;  //Flag for switch
        private boolean visible; 
        private int     width;  
        private int     height;  

        private int _xOffset = 0;
        private int _yOffset = 0;

        final Animation translateAnimation;


        private final Runnable drawThread=new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                drawFrame();
            }
        };


        public WallpaperEngine(Resources r) {
            image01=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r,R.drawable.fire01);
            image02=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r,R.drawable.fire02);
            bg=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r,R.drawable.hktv);
            px=1;
            translateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.translate_animation);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
            super.onCreate(surfaceHolder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawThread);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
            int format,int width,int height) {
            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder,format,width,height);
            this.width =width;
            this.height=height;
            drawFrame();
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceCreated(holder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSurfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            super.onSurfaceDestroyed(holder);
            visible=false;
            handler.removeCallbacks(drawThread);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisibilityChanged(boolean visible) {
            this.visible=visible;
            if (visible) {
                drawFrame();
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacks(drawThread);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onOffsetsChanged(float xOffset,float yOffset,
            float xStep,float yStep,int xPixels,int yPixels) {
            _xOffset = xPixels;
            _yOffset = yPixels;
            drawFrame();
        }

        private void drawFrame() {

            SurfaceHolder holder=getSurfaceHolder();
            Canvas c=holder.lockCanvas();

            c.drawBitmap(bg, _xOffset, _yOffset, paint);
            //c.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
            if (px == 1) {
                image=image01;
                px=2;
            } else {
                image=image02;
                px=1 ;
            }
            c.drawBitmap(image, (width-image.getWidth())/2, (height-image.getHeight())/2, null);

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);





            handler.removeCallbacks(drawThread);
            if (visible) handler.postDelayed(drawThread,100);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `R.anim.translate_animation` instead of `android.R.anim.translate_animation` to import animation for `res/anim` resource  :

```
    translateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                                           R.anim.translate_animation);
```

Comment: After removed android. : cannot find symbol variable anim

Comment: @hkguile :  make sure you have placed `translate_animation.xml` file inside `res/anim/` folder. if `anim` folder not exist then create it in `res` folder

Comment: @hkguile : try after cleaning project

Comment: loadAnimation(android.content.Context,int) in android.view.animation.AnimationUtils cannot be applied to (com.example.android.livewallpaper.FireLiveWallpaper.WallpaperEngine,int)

Comment: i have changed this to getApplicationContext(), seem it works now